# Visual Studio Code cursor jumps to end of file

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to use VS Code to edit an existing HTML file.

When I try to enter a new paragraph after I type `<p`, when I type the closing bracket,`>`, it is entered at the end of the document after the closing `</html>` tag, so I have `</html>>` as the last line of the document. The curser is also right there at the end of the document, instead of where I was trying to make a new text entry.

I must be missing something very simple, but I sure can't find it in the volumes and volumes of documentation.

I have other problems too, but if I could learn how to enter new text it would get me started!

I'm afraid VS Code is one of those apps that is so 'capable' that, as a beginner,  it is hard to get all the options right.

Thanks.

Comment: Was there any issues during instalation? Maybe just reinstall?

Answer (score 3):

You have auto-save and auto code formatting enabled.

Disable code formatting on save (File > Preferences).

In my case, code formatting was disabled, but a rogue formatting extension (plugin) was causing problems. Uninstall formatting extensions to find which one.

Comment: This does work, but is such a bad thing to have to do to fix it.   I have tried disabling various extensions also to see if that had an impacted (as some other resources have suggested), but disabling auto-save seems to be the most reliable fix.  There must be a better fix though.  Thanks!